# How to create an alias for unresolved apt dependencies?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, aptitude, dependencies

Some time ago I installed a `wormsarmageddon.deb` that depended on a package named `wine`. Since no distribution package or PPA I could find provided a package named `wine` -- but only `wine-stable`, `wine-staging`, `wine-devel` etc. -- I ended up installing `wormsarmageddon` with `sudo dpkg --ignore-depends wine -i wormsarmageddon.deb` and everything worked well.

Now, every time I try to install anything with `apt-get` or `aptitude` it fails because of that. See an example below:

```
fiatjaf@menger ~ [1]> sudo aptitude install openjdk-9-jdk
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates-java{a} dbus-x11{a} java-common{a} libatk-wrapper-java{a} 
  libatk-wrapper-java-jni{a} libbonobo2-0{a} libbonobo2-common{a} libgnome-2-0{a} 
  libgnome2-common{a} libgnomevfs2-0{a} libgnomevfs2-common{a} liborbit-2-0{a} 
  openjdk-9-jdk openjdk-9-jdk-headless{a} openjdk-9-jre{a} openjdk-9-jre-headless{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 16 newly installed, 0 to remove and 183 not upgraded.
Need to get 118 MB of archives. After unpacking 279 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wormsarmageddon : Depends: wine (>= 1.2.1) which is a virtual package, provided by:
                            - winehq-staging (2.9.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-staging (2.8.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-staging (2.7.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-staging (2.6.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-staging (2.5.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-staging (2.4.0-3~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-staging (2.18.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-staging (2.17.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-staging (2.16.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-staging (2.15.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-staging (2.14.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-staging (2.13.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-staging (2.12.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-staging (2.11.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-staging (2.10.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-stable (2.0.2~zesty), but 2.0.2~zesty is installed
                            - winehq-stable (2.0.1~zesty), but 2.0.2~zesty is installed
                            - winehq-stable (2.0.0~zesty), but 2.0.2~zesty is installed
                            - winehq-devel (2.9.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-devel (2.8.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-devel (2.7.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-devel (2.6.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-devel (2.5.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-devel (2.4.0-3~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-devel (2.18.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-devel (2.17.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-devel (2.16.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-devel (2.15.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-devel (2.14.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-devel (2.13.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-devel (2.12.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-devel (2.11.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-devel (2.10.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - wine-stable (1.8.7-1ubuntu1), but 2.0.2~zesty is installed
                            - wine-development (2.0-3ubuntu1), but it is not going to be installed

The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Remove the following packages:              
1)     wormsarmageddon [3.7.2.1-0 (now, testing)]



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

What bugs me is that `wine` is recognized as a "virtual package" for all the other "wines", some of them are indeed installed.

So, how do I solve this situation?

---

**UPDATE**:

So, following suggestions from comments, I tried to reinstall wine. `apt` complained about many things, but it seems indeed that wine wasn't properly installed (note that now the output is "to be installed", instead of "is installed" from before -- I don't know why).

```
fiatjaf@menger ~> sudo apt-get install --reinstall wine-stable
[sudo] password for fiatjaf: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openjdk-9-jre-headless : Depends: ca-certificates-java but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: java-common (>= 0.28) but it is not going to be installed
 wine-stable : Depends: wine-stable-amd64 (= 2.0.3~zesty) but 2.0.2~zesty is to be installed
               Depends: wine-stable-i386 (= 2.0.3~zesty)
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 2.0.2~zesty)
 wormsarmageddon : Depends: wine (>= 1.2.1)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Running `apt --fix-broken install` still removed `wormsarmaggedon`, but then I was able to run `apt-get install --reinstall wine-stable`, which in the end didn't fix anything:

```
fiatjaf@menger ~ [130]> sudo apt-get install wormsarmageddon
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wormsarmageddon : Depends: wine (>= 1.2.1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
fiatjaf@menger ~ [100]> sudo aptitude install wormsarmageddon
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  wormsarmageddon{b} 
0 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 203 not upgraded.
Need to get 111 MB of archives. After unpacking 164 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wormsarmageddon : Depends: wine (>= 1.2.1) which is a virtual package, provided by:
                            - winehq-staging (2.9.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-staging (2.8.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-staging (2.7.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-staging (2.6.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-staging (2.5.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-staging (2.4.0-3~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-staging (2.19.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-staging (2.18.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-staging (2.17.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-staging (2.16.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-staging (2.15.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-staging (2.14.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-staging (2.13.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-staging (2.12.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-staging (2.11.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-staging (2.10.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-stable (2.0.3~zesty), but 2.0.3~zesty is installed
                            - winehq-stable (2.0.2~zesty), but 2.0.3~zesty is installed
                            - winehq-stable (2.0.1~zesty), but 2.0.3~zesty is installed
                            - winehq-stable (2.0.0~zesty), but 2.0.3~zesty is installed
                            - winehq-devel (2.9.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-devel (2.8.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-devel (2.7.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-devel (2.6.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-devel (2.5.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-devel (2.4.0-3~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-devel (2.19.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-devel (2.18.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-devel (2.17.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-devel (2.16.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-devel (2.15.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-devel (2.14.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-devel (2.13.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-devel (2.12.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-devel (2.11.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - winehq-devel (2.10.0~zesty), but it is not going to be installed
                            - wine-stable (1.8.7-1ubuntu1), but 2.0.3~zesty is installed
                            - wine-development (2.0-3ubuntu1), but it is not going to be installed

The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     wormsarmageddon [Not Installed]                    



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
fiatjaf@menger ~ [130]> apt-cache show winehq-stable
Package: winehq-stable
Source: wine-stable
Version: 2.0.3~zesty
Architecture: amd64
Maintainer: WineHQ Builds <builds@wine-staging.com>
Installed-Size: 72
Depends: wine-stable (= 2.0.3~zesty)
Conflicts: wine, wine-amd64, wine-i386
Replaces: wine, wine-amd64, wine-i386, wine1.4, wine1.4-amd64, wine1.4-i386, wine1.5, wine1.5-amd64, wine1.5-i386, wine1.6, wine1.6-amd64, wine1.6-i386, wine1.7, wine1.7-amd64, wine1.7-i386, wine32, wine64
Provides: wine, wine-amd64, wine-i386, wine1.4, wine1.4-amd64, wine1.4-i386, wine1.5, wine1.5-amd64, wine1.5-i386, wine1.6, wine1.6-amd64, wine1.6-i386, wine1.7, wine1.7-amd64, wine1.7-i386, wine32, wine64
Section: otherosfs
Priority: optional
Description: WINE Is Not An Emulator - runs MS Windows programs
 Wine is a program which allows running Microsoft Windows programs
 (including DOS, Windows 3.x and Win32 executables) on Unix.
 .
 This compatibility package allows to use wine-stable system-wide as
 the default Wine version.
Description-md5: 3c434a64434281e632d12fce500efde1
Original-Maintainer: Scott Ritchie <scottritchie@ubuntu.com>
SHA256: 0ca3ecc91b6926ef78f1a6dbe0d96386e994a8b82996da9a0149f6e4edf2dccf
SHA1: dc3156459a2067aaff73aed2e2fc17654a9fbb05
MD5sum: 3a0354e587fb2909a3a79f4f2621a6b8
Size: 3130
Filename: pool/main/winehq-stable_2.0.3~zesty_amd64.deb

Package: winehq-stable
Source: wine-stable
Version: 2.0.2~zesty
Architecture: amd64
Maintainer: WineHQ Builds <builds@wine-staging.com>
Installed-Size: 72
Depends: wine-stable (= 2.0.2~zesty)
Conflicts: wine, wine-amd64, wine-i386
Replaces: wine, wine-amd64, wine-i386, wine1.4, wine1.4-amd64, wine1.4-i386, wine1.5, wine1.5-amd64, wine1.5-i386, wine1.6, wine1.6-amd64, wine1.6-i386, wine1.7, wine1.7-amd64, wine1.7-i386, wine32, wine64
Provides: wine, wine-amd64, wine-i386, wine1.4, wine1.4-amd64, wine1.4-i386, wine1.5, wine1.5-amd64, wine1.5-i386, wine1.6, wine1.6-amd64, wine1.6-i386, wine1.7, wine1.7-amd64, wine1.7-i386, wine32, wine64
Section: otherosfs
Priority: optional
Description: WINE Is Not An Emulator - runs MS Windows programs
 Wine is a program which allows running Microsoft Windows programs
 (including DOS, Windows 3.x and Win32 executables) on Unix.
 .
 This compatibility package allows to use wine-stable system-wide as
 the default Wine version.
Description-md5: 3c434a64434281e632d12fce500efde1
Original-Maintainer: Scott Ritchie <scottritchie@ubuntu.com>
SHA256: 743af1b4a7c44653b0956d9e591dece336a56dee7155c1226165a324ea3b4fd6
SHA1: 63c0fb5da967f3243313cb85274f8c8b90e7662a
MD5sum: 0e97b1df770e490cc491c9b4ffc12232
Size: 3134
Filename: pool/main/winehq-stable_2.0.2~zesty_amd64.deb

Package: winehq-stable
Source: wine-stable
Version: 2.0.1~zesty
Architecture: amd64
Maintainer: WineHQ Builds <builds@wine-staging.com>
Installed-Size: 72
Depends: wine-stable (= 2.0.1~zesty)
Conflicts: wine, wine-amd64, wine-i386
Replaces: wine, wine-amd64, wine-i386, wine1.4, wine1.4-amd64, wine1.4-i386, wine1.5, wine1.5-amd64, wine1.5-i386, wine1.6, wine1.6-amd64, wine1.6-i386, wine1.7, wine1.7-amd64, wine1.7-i386, wine32, wine64
Provides: wine, wine-amd64, wine-i386, wine1.4, wine1.4-amd64, wine1.4-i386, wine1.5, wine1.5-amd64, wine1.5-i386, wine1.6, wine1.6-amd64, wine1.6-i386, wine1.7, wine1.7-amd64, wine1.7-i386, wine32, wine64
Section: otherosfs
Priority: optional
Description: WINE Is Not An Emulator - runs MS Windows programs
 Wine is a program which allows running Microsoft Windows programs
 (including DOS, Windows 3.x and Win32 executables) on Unix.
 .
 This compatibility package allows to use wine-stable system-wide as
 the default Wine version.
Description-md5: 3c434a64434281e632d12fce500efde1
Original-Maintainer: Scott Ritchie <scottritchie@ubuntu.com>
SHA256: 9abb20a44473549e5ab098653baec4d8fabbc6b6237d8db9bf4b0616112f8db5
SHA1: 3465d8f11f5aefe7f6c02d391a580f189d6a5856
MD5sum: 0e1a22bb84112fa435c5f5dead3d7738
Size: 3134
Filename: pool/main/winehq-stable_2.0.1~zesty_amd64.deb

Package: winehq-stable
Source: wine-stable
Version: 2.0.0~zesty
Architecture: amd64
Maintainer: Michael Müller <michael@fds-team.de>
Installed-Size: 72
Depends: wine-stable (= 2.0.0~zesty)
Conflicts: wine, wine-amd64, wine-i386
Replaces: wine, wine-amd64, wine-i386, wine1.4, wine1.4-amd64, wine1.4-i386, wine1.5, wine1.5-amd64, wine1.5-i386, wine1.6, wine1.6-amd64, wine1.6-i386, wine1.7, wine1.7-amd64, wine1.7-i386, wine32, wine64
Provides: wine, wine-amd64, wine-i386, wine1.4, wine1.4-amd64, wine1.4-i386, wine1.5, wine1.5-amd64, wine1.5-i386, wine1.6, wine1.6-amd64, wine1.6-i386, wine1.7, wine1.7-amd64, wine1.7-i386, wine32, wine64
Section: otherosfs
Priority: optional
Description: WINE Is Not An Emulator - runs MS Windows programs
 Wine is a program which allows running Microsoft Windows programs
 (including DOS, Windows 3.x and Win32 executables) on Unix.
 .
 This compatibility package allows to use wine-stable system-wide as
 the default Wine version.
Description-md5: 3c434a64434281e632d12fce500efde1
Original-Maintainer: Scott Ritchie <scottritchie@ubuntu.com>
SHA256: 7bfd03bb3edb938c94f540002fc5555487fb0ae754bf7badfb257d31b0baf327
SHA1: 54c1dd180af278139f01c02d1fd9fbb1ce49373a
MD5sum: 610ba09ee83f5a6727f1eb53d47f8d30
Size: 3132
Filename: pool/main/winehq-stable_2.0.0~zesty_amd64.deb
```

Comment: So... how did you end up installing `wine`? `apt install wine-stable`?

Comment: Yes, @Bob. That's how I did it.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the Wine -package? ( sudo apt-get install --reinstall wine-stable ) Or --purge'd it then installed again? Have you added any repositories yourself, sometimes they can bugger up apt.

Comment: Are you able to use wine (and run wormsarmageddon)?

Comment: "`wine` is provided by `winehq-stable (2.0.2~zesty), but 2.0.2~zesty is installed`" looks very wrong, as if `winehq-stable` was not completely installed... what's the output of `apt-cache show winehq-stable`?

Comment: @Shaido, @DocWeird, @dirkt, thank you very much for your responses. I've updated the question to include your suggestions and output of commands. Everything is still the same. I've now removed `wormsarmageddon`, but I should be able to install it. Let me clarify that I'm using [a PPA](https://themassacre.org/apt/) for that, but it was running fine with my previous setup (before asking the question, the one that `apt` didn't like) and probably using the default `wine` provided by `wine-stable`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late reply, but `wine-stable` from the distro repos is too outdated, add the [official Wine repos](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu), and do:

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt remove *wine*
sudo apt install winehq-staging wine-staging-amd64 wine-staging-i386 wine-staging
sudo apt install ./armageddon.deb
```

The `wine-devel` should work as well, but `wine-staging` has extra features in the staging tab of the Wine configurator, so that's why I am recommending it.